# CUDA 2D Arrays - Accounting for pitch prior to allocation?

Tags: cuda, multidimensional-array, pitch

I have a workflow that operates as follows:

1. Load Initial Values
2. Process Values to Intermediate Results A
3. Process A to Intermediate Results B
4. Process B to Intermediate Results C
5. Process C and B to Intermediate Results D and E
6. Sum Partial D to Final Result F

The natural structure for all of my intermediate results is that of a 2D array, which I am allocating with cudaMallocPitch().

Unfortunately, my algorithm requires that I keep D, E, C, and B in memory all at once, and D & E are, individually, 4x larger in memory than B. Because of another restriction in my processing (iterating over a graph structure in memory), the dimensions of A or B are bounded by the maximum dimensions of D and E, which in turn are determined by the memory usage of the initial values + B's memory consumption + C's memory consumption. This dependency is because I am "paging" sections of the intermediate results to/from device memory from the host (to accommodate very large problem sets), and I can't begin step 4 until steps 1-3 have been completed for the entire problem set.

Once I have B for the entire problem set, I can delete A.

I am currently determining the maximum size of D+E with the following function:

```
int gpuCalculateSimulPatterns(int lines, int patterns) {
    // get free memory
    size_t free_mem, total_mem;
    int allowed_patterns;
    cudaMemGetInfo(&free_mem, &total_mem);
    allowed_patterns = (free_mem - (lines*sizeof(int))) / (lines*(sizeof(int)*2.5) + lines*sizeof(char)*1.5);
    return min(patterns, allowed_patterns -(allowed_patterns % 32));
}
```

It "works", but only because I'm overestimating the size of D or E (their dimensions and memory usage are identical) by 25% and doubling the expected size of B. Even then, I still run into edge cases where my memory allocation fails because it's run out of memory. I want to make more efficient use of the memory on the card *and* maintain alignment, as my kernels make multiple reads and writes from/to global memory.

No, using shared memory is not an option, as I'm using multiple kernels across multiple blocks, and the threads within a block don't interact at all.

I've found that cudaMallocPitch() only returns the used pitch for memory that has been successfully allocated. Is there a way to hand the driver a 2D memory allocation request and just ask for the pitch it would assign?

I'd rig up a trial/error optimization routine, but the linked dependency of dimension between A, B, D, and E (C I calculate apriori as it is not allocated pitch-linear) makes this a lousy solution and it'd need to be recalculated for every problem set.

Does anyone have a better approach that would allow me to determine an appropriate size of my intermediate datasets that will fit in an arbitrary amount of device memory?

EDIT:

The memory for intermediate A is being reused, my bounding calculations makes the assumption that C+D+E+B >> Initial + A + B (which is true by virtue of the fact that A & B are 1-byte chars of the same dimensions, while C,D,E are ints) and such I only need to ensure there's enough space for B + C + D + E.

I'm only using Compute Capability 2.x cards to test this with (Quadro 2000,  Tesla C2075, GTX460).

Comment: Is pitch allocation wasting much memory?  Do you have an example of how much?  Is it enough to worry about?   If so, you might consider doing linear memory allocation, and linearizing your indices.  (Also, from your dependency chain looks like the memory for intermediate A could be reused).

Comment: The main reason I'm using pitch-linear memory is to take advantage of coalescing, and because the results from position (X, Y) in one process are used again for (X,Y) in another process.

The pitch allocation is wasting a variable amount of memory. I think it's holding it to the nearest 512 bytes, at least for one of the cards I'm testing it on.

Comment: You don't need pitch linear to get coalescing.  You just need (on Fermi) for addresses for each load in a warp to fall into a single aligned 128-byte cache line.  You will never get cache reuse across processes, so I'm not sure why that is relevant.  Perhaps I misunderstand.  If your pattern of locality within warps is 2D (and has good spatial locality), then you would be better served by using texture accesses since the hardware texture cache and texture memory layout is optimized for 2D locality, whereas pitch linear is still, well, linear.

Comment: Every step of my application reads and writes to global memory, and every intermediate process is a separate kernel that is being executed. I know that cache isn't reused between kernels (although some of my benchmark results make me wonder about that).

Comment: Access pattern is aligned properly for coalescing. I'm reading and writing within a kernel. Shared memory is out because the intermediate results for a single block need to be available in global memory anyway.

Texture memory is out because I writes and my datasets are guaranteed to be larger than the texture cache anyway and the maximum texture size. Surfaces are also too small.

Comment: Note that I didn't say you won't get reuse between kernels.  I said that you won't get reuse between processes (due to context switch).  You said (X, Y) in one *process* is reused for (X, Y) in another *process*.  Perhaps by *process* you mean GPU thread?

Comment: I'm using "Process" as a verb; referring to the work a kernel does on a section of data. Each "Process" statement translates to a kernel call (everything working on A uses the same kernel, etc).

Comment: "because the results from position (X, Y) in one process are used again for (X,Y) in another process"...  hmmm, that's a noun in my language. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pitch in bytes is calculated this way:

```
pitch_size = DIV_UP(width_in_bytes, prop.textureAlignment);
```

Where DIV_UP rounds the first argument up to the next higher multiple of the second argument.

You can query `prop.textureAlignment` by calling `cudaGetDeviceProperties()`.

Comment: While I couldn't find DIV_UP in the cuda docs, this is the same effect as a macro:

`#define DIV_UP(x,y) (((x%y) > 0) ? ((x/y)+((x%y) > 0))*y: x)`

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use modulo, that's a pretty expensive way to do it.  I would use `#define DIV_UP(x, y) ( (y) * ( ((x)+(y)-1) / (y) ) )`

Comment: I'm not using the macro in GPU code and the code is used sparingly. Thanks for the heads-up though.

Comment: So does this mean that prop.textureAlignment is also used for global memory minimum pitches (as returned by e.g. cudaMalloc3D or cudaMallocPitch)?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the pitch in bytes be:

```
pitch_size = DIV_UP(width_in_bytes, prop.textureAlignment)*prop.textureAlignment;
```

instead of:

```
pitch_size = DIV_UP(width_in_bytes, prop.textureAlignment);
```